# React codecoverage with react-scripts

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, puppeteer

I have an app created with `create-react-app` and some E2E tests (Jest + Puppeteer)

I like to get coverage but something is going wrong.
I see always 100% for `Branch` and `Funcs` columns, and always 0% for `Lines` column.

[image]